# How to develop ms excel ribbon functions

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, vsto

how to develop ms excel ribbon functionality not COM add-ins or VSTO add-ins. Using visual studio
Thank you

I want to implement excel ribbon functions to validate voucher, but i cannot use com-addins or vsto-addins in visual studio. Any alternatives to develop that integration ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the new Excel add-in framework that uses JavaScript. It also supports adding buttons in the ribbon. More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview